# How to open .exj file extension

Tags: file-extension, file-types

I need to open .exj file extension. I googled and found it's associated with Java. But how do I open it to view and edit the contents of the file? One thing I am aware, it has question and answers in it. I think it acts like a database. The file name is qpool.exe which means question pool. It was part of a exam practice test software.

Comment: We need more context. Where did you find this file? Have you taken a look at the file's header? Everyone can save anything in a file with *any* extension (extensions are just an addition to a file name, they don't mean anything apart from providing a hint of what to expect the file to contain).

Comment: I have edited the question with more details. Hope it helps and thanks for your support.

Comment: If it is part of a professional software solution, it might as well be an encrypted, closed-source, proprietary format that may require reverse-engineering.